# PHP MYSQL SIMPLE SEARCH ISSUE

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a table with the following structure:

`id int(11),
name varchar(250)`

I have lots of records in the table but when I am trying to find a particluar record which has the following value on the name field:
Lorem ipsum d\'olor sit amet
The query is simply returning a blank recordset. I am not being able to figure out this weird behaviour, when my query is as simple as follows:

`SELECT * FROM slot_games WHERE name='Lorem ipsum d\'olor sit amet'`

Would appreciate your help please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** (or `addslashes`) function before the `name` field.

**Example:**

```
$name = "Lorem ipsum d'olor sit amet";
"SELECT * FROM slot_games WHERE name='$name'";
```

This will basically escape the `'` character and that's probably why you have the problem.

Comment: If you notice the query I have posted the single quote is already escaped by adding a backslash before it. So what you are suggesting is already being done, still it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this issue

```
1. use mysql_real_escape_string(); // used in the Query
2. addslashes();                   // used in php before query execution
```